# 2 client socket without serverSocket

Tags: java, sockets, connection, serversocket

Im trying to build a communication between two Sockets without using any server Socket. I know that server Socket has ServerSocket.accept() method which waits for incoming connections. But when i try to open a socket to an ip which has no server Socket, i keep getting an exception:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
    at client1.<init>(client1.java:13)
    at client1Main.main(client1Main.java:9)
```

This is first code that im executing:

```
public class client1 {
    public client1() {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1",15123);
             BufferedReader in 
                = new BufferedReader(
                      new InputStreamReader(
                          socket.getInputStream()));
              PrintWriter out 
                = new PrintWriter(
                      new OutputStreamWriter(
                          socket.getOutputStream())); 
              while(true) {
                  System.out.println(in.readLine());
              }
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

public class client1Main {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    new client1();
}
```

}

Is there something that im missing?

Comment: Why no server socket? This does not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong tool for the job. Not using `ServerSocket` suggests not using TCP. That leaves UDP, which means you should switch to using `DatagramSocket`.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately im restricted with the TCP in my case. But i got what you mean, thanks for the quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

You simply can't do that.

You need something that listens on the port you try to connect to, and that's done with server sockets.

There is no workaround for TCP.

Comment: But the problem here, at least in my application (this code was just for testing), if i make a listener for that port, any connection from outside my application might send data over that port. It is a kind of leak without any protection.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu the same will be true for any other socket API you'll find.

Comment: @BarışcanKayaoğlu: Not having a server socket doesn't solve that problem. Anyone would be able to connect to your clients in your scenario.